# Net Core Automatically Review Unoptimized Entity Framework Queries

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

We have a team of application developers creating Entity framework queries. Most of the time, Entity Framework Core prepare good queries; however sometimes they become unoptimized and long.

Is there a method to automatically detect unoptimized Entity Framework Linq queries in the code? Typically what we do, is run we run all our EF repository and services in Integration tests, then manually review the SQL DMV for unoptimized queries.

Is there a framework or better methodology setup to automatically conduct this in Visual Studio or other tool?